# c# Wrapper for CNTK steps

Tags: c#, cntk

I'm having some issues at running CNTK on c# wrapper. I see rold2007 had success on doing the same thing. There got to be something simple that I missed. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The steps I used are as follow:

1. use the [source code from  C#](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Source/Extensibility/CSEvalClient)
2. generate a new dos application and copy the new code to it.
3. building the program, the following error occurred at line
   `using (var model = new IEvaluateModelManagedF())`
   Wit error message:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'IEvaluateModelManagedF' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

VS version: vs community 2015
OS: windows 10.
CNTK: Downloaded binary. Able to run a sample program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project needs to reference `EvalWrapper.dll`. In the same directory as the DLL, you need to have a list of other DLLs that are used. See the detailed discussion [on the CNTK GitHub page](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/issues/394). If you are running a CPU-only build, this is the list of DLLs:

- `EvalDll.dll`
- `EvalWrapper.dll`
- `libacml_mp_dll.dll`
- `libifcoremd.dll`
- `libifportmd.dll`
- `libiomp5md.dll`
- `libmmd.dll`
- `Math.dll`
- `svml_dispmd.dll`

**Update**

CNTK has switched from ACML to Intel MKL as of August 2016 [(see Release Notes)](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/CNTK_1_6_Release_Notes). After this change, the list of required DLLs is

- `EvalDll.dll`
- `EvalDll.lib`
- `EvalWrapper.dll`
- `Math.dll`
- `libiomp5md.dll`
- `mkl_cntk_p.dll`

Comment: Thanks for the help. adding the reference got me further. However, I still encounter some additional compiling  errors. model.CreateNetwork(string.Format("modelPath=\"{0}\"", modelFilePath), device