# Assembly loading fails with CNTK EvalWrapper

Tags: visual-studio, cntk

I have a .NET assembly with some tests that references CNTK's `EvalWrapper.dll`. The CNTK build is targeting x64, the .NET test assembly has build target AnyCPU. I have ensured that all required DLLs are available in the build output directory, [see this SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990833/c-sharp-wrapper-for-cntk-steps). I've chosen x64 in VS Test Settings / Processor Architecture.

My tests ran fine for a while, but now started to fail with an assembly loading error, `BadImageFormatException` when loading `EvalWrapper.dll`. Inspecting the loading errors with the Fusion Log Viewer also did not reveal anything beyond the incorrect format:

```
The operation failed.
Bind result: hr = 0x8007000b. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\te.processhost.managed.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = EvalWrapper, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

There is nothing I've changed in my project setup. What could have changed silently that makes my tests now all fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the culprit was a 32bit test execution engine that had been still running in the background - even though I had made sure that "Test Settings / Keep Test Execution Engine Running" was not ticked. I had a moment yesterday where I noticed that VS had "forgotten" my choice of processor architecture, and it was reset to 32 bit. I changed it back to 64 bit - with hindsight, I guess that's where the problem started.

VS silently changing the processor architecture for tests is something I had noticed previously in other projects, too.

Closing and re-opening VS did the trick, all tests now pass again. Alternatively, I could probably have looked for all test execution engine processes that were running, and kill those.