# CNTK c# Wrapper throws "External component has thrown an exception." for EvalWrapper

Tags: c#, cntk

I have the code for CSEvalClientTest.csproj from Microsoft's CNTK on GitHub. I've created a new Visual Studio 2015 c# console app, pasted in the code from CSEvalClientTest.csproj, fixed the references and got it to run. It doesn't get very far though. On this line of source code:
                **using (var model = new IEvaluateModelManagedF())**
It throws this exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException was unhandled
```

- ErrorCode=-2147467259   HResult=-2147467259   Message=External
  component has thrown an exception.   Source=hhCSEvalClientTest
  StackTrace:
        at Microsoft.MSR.CNTK.Extensibility.Managed.CSEvalClient.Program.OnGeneralException(Exception
  ex) in
  E:\Users\Hal\Source\Workspaces\hhCSEvalClientTest\hhCSEvalClientTest\hhCSEvalClientTest\Program.cs:line
  123
        at Microsoft.MSR.CNTK.Extensibility.Managed.CSEvalClient.Program.EvaluateModelSingleLayer()
  in
  E:\Users\Hal\Source\Workspaces\hhCSEvalClientTest\hhCSEvalClientTest\hhCSEvalClientTest\Program.cs:line
  171
        at Microsoft.MSR.CNTK.Extensibility.Managed.CSEvalClient.Program.Main(String[]
  args) in
  E:\Users\Hal\Source\Workspaces\hhCSEvalClientTest\hhCSEvalClientTest\hhCSEvalClientTest\Program.cs:line
  69
        at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
        at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
  executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
  preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
  preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

**Any help resolving this issue will be very much appreciated!**

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to use [CNTK Nuget Package](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/NuGet-Package) for your C# application? This would remove most headaches regarding dll references. You can look at the example in https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/tree/master/Examples/Evaluation/CSEvalClient for more information.

Comment: Good point, yes - if using the standard build without modifications, the Nuget package should be easier than custom referencing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I may come back to it later. For now, I'm hoping I can fix up the references. I have trouble using Git and have never used Nuget. I want to learn about CNTK while minimizing the other tools I need to learn to get it up and running.

Comment: After so much struggling, I think Zhou's suggestion is the way to go. Using nuget is very simple really. In VS, use Tools/NugetPackageManger/ManagePackagesForSolution. Pick nuget.org, search for "CNTK" in the "search online" box. Then you can pick which projects should get the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, you are missing some of the referenced native DLLs. Have a look at [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990833/c-sharp-wrapper-for-cntk-steps) for a list of DLLs. Those need to reside in the same directory as your main executable.

Note that you will have to add the correct set of references for all DLLs or EXEs that use `EvalWrapper`, which is a cumbersome. I've found it helpful to work with a `props` file, that you reference in your project files. Here's how my `cntk_evalwrapper.props` looks like (you need to adjust the location of your CNTK build)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="c:/git/cntk/x64/Release_CpuOnly/EvalDll.dll">
      <Link>evaldll.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="c:/git/cntk/x64/Release_CpuOnly/EvalDll.lib">
      <Link>EvalDll.lib</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="c:/git/cntk/x64/Release_CpuOnly/Math.dll">
      <Link>Math.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="c:/git/cntk/x64/Release_CpuOnly/libiomp5md.dll">
      <Link>libiomp5md.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Include="c:/git/cntk/x64/Release_CpuOnly/mkl_cntk_p.dll">
      <Link>mkl_cntk_p.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <Reference Include="EvalWrapper">
      <HintPath>c:/git/cntk/x64/Release_CpuOnly/EvalWrapper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In your project file `yourproject.csproj`, include this props file, so that the top of your project file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Import Project="..\cntk_evalwrapper.props" />
```

Again, adjust the relative path such that it correctly points from your project file to the props file. If that worked correctly, you should see a reference to `EvalWrapper` in your project's references once you re-load the project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm struggling with adding the other DLLs. I can add and remove EvalWrapper.dll without trouble. But the rest of them from your link fail with the error: **A reference to the "....dll" could not be added.Please make sure that the file is accessible and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.**.  I've added the DLLs to the directory you suggested: **..\obj\x64\Debug**, but I'm still getting the same error. I've googled adding references, and find a lot of different approaches - none of which feel 'right'. Would you point me in the right direction?

Comment: `EvalWrapper.dll` is the only reference that you need to add. For all the other DLLs, do not try to add them as references - they only must sit in the same directory as `EvalWrapper.dll`. I would really suggest you go the way of the props file. May seem daunting at first to mess with the .csproj file, but makes live a lot easier. Right-click on the project, "Unload project", then "Edit project file", do your edits, then "Re-load project". Make sure you save backup of your project file first.

Comment: Thanks again! I wrestled with this for a while and some progress.  The changes to the .csproj file seem good. The code follows in the next comment. sorry, but I can't get the formatting to work.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\cntk_evalwrapper.props" />

Comment: My project builds fine. The reference to EvalWrapper appears, and if I delete it, it reappears when I reopen the project. When I run the project form Visual Studio, it crashes with a **vshost.exe has stopped working**  *A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.* That occurs at the same point in the code where the exception was being thrown previously.

Comment: The slash,backslash pair in your props file example seems odd. I changed it to just a slash, but that made no difference, so I've changed it back. My .props file follows in the next comment. I'm using the CPU plus GPU version of the code. I got the first Python/Jupyter tutorial to work, so I assume that's not an issue. My .props file is in the next comment.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="E:\Users\Hal\Source\Workspaces\CSEvalClientTest\CSEvalClientTest\CSEvalClientTest\obj\x64\Debug\/EvalDll.dll">
      <Link>evaldll.dll</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
...
    <Reference Include="EvalWrapper">
      <HintPath>E:\Users\Hal\Source\Workspaces\CSEvalClientTest\CSEvalClientTest\CSEvalClientTest\obj\x64\Debug\/EvalWrapper.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Comment: Any thoughts as to what I might try next?

Comment: Did you verify that the DLLs in question actually exist in the directory you are using? If you are using the default CNTK build setup and output folders, I don't think you would ever see DLLs in `CSEvalClientTest\CS‌​EvalClientTest\CSEva‌​lClientTest\obj\x64\‌​Debug\`